# Issue with passing props in react navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I want to create a custom header and i am going to make an arrow icon, but this arrow icon won't bring back users to previous page, i want to have control on it to determine which screen it should bring back
I have three screens `Home`, `screen 1` and `screen 2`

I've created a custom header for screen 2 with a arrow icon, I want it bring back users to home screen after being clicked.

This is header code:

```
const Header =(props)=>{

 const {navigation}=props;

return(

<View>

<Icon onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('props.destination')} />

</View>
```

And this is the code of screen 2:

```
import {Header} from './';


const Screen2 = (props) => {

  const {navigation}=props;

  return (
  <Fragment>
    <Header  destination='Home' navigation={navigation}  />
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Text>Screen2</Text>
      </View>
      </Fragment>

  )

}
```

This the error i am getting, How can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any variable `destination` being used, only a prop assignment. And this: `navigation.navigate('props.destination')` is trying to use a string value, not a prop. Is this the exact code you used when that error happened?

Comment: Yes i exactly used this code, What is the solution?

Comment: I passed a props like this ```navigation.navigate(props.destination)``` It didn't work either

Comment: what's the error message after changing to `navigation.navigate(props.destination)`

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu I am getting same error

Comment: The error has to be coming from somewhere else. You aren't using `destination` in the code you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually want to pass the string stored in `props.destination` (`'Home'` in this case) to `navigate()` rather than the string literal `'props.destination'` which is not a valid screen name:

```
<Icon onPress={()=>navigation.navigate(props.destination)} />
```

Comment: @roz333 What is the error if you do it like this? `navigation.navigate('props.destination')` is definitely not correct either. How did you define your Screens?

Comment: I am getting same error, I passed like this ```navigation.navigate(props.destination)``` It didn't work either, I already wrote my screen code

Comment: @roz333 Where are your Screens defined? You did not provide that code. You must have some `Stack.Navigator` somewhere.

Comment: check if `Header` is imported correctly `import {Header} from './`

Comment: It worked, I had made a mistake in stack navigation, Thank you buddy